# How can i have a fullscreen video on pc

Tags: pro-tools

I work with protools 10 hd on pc.  l know protools has fitscreen option but l need to have the fullscreeen version on my tv.    How can l do this?

Comment: Perhaps the fitscreen on the software is conflicting with your TV's hardware? Try changing the screen size options on your tv.